# eciesjs while decryption getting error ` Error: Expected private key to be an Uint8Array with length 32`

Tags: node.js, encryption, public-key-encryption, cryptojs, ecies

I am using **eciesjs** npm package for encryption and decryption inside this encryption was done successfully but at the time of decryption getting error :  Error: Expected private key to be an Uint8Array with length 32.

here is my code as below:

```
import eciesjs from 'eciesjs'
const key=`0x12bcb941510e4a02037e03904554064a6bce209155572d69fd22c46cc4e68c3dae9175c4177d844f9a0114b85a1e0129a14ec33c3ebd64e144faa6c069581472`
const data= 'My text abc'
const cipher = eciesjs.encrypt(key, Buffer.from(data))
const encryptedData = cipher.toString('hex')
console.log('encryptedData ', encryptedData)

const decryptData = eciesjs.decrypt(key, encryptedData).toString()
console.log('decryptData = ', decryptData)
```

At the time of decryption I am getting error as bellow:

```
error: Error: Expected private key to be an Uint8Array with length 32
```

Comment: The error message already describes it: For decryption the private key is needed and not the public one.